# Tokenize a corpus of 10 documents in Python

Tags: python, tokenize, tf-idf

I am new to coding in Python so figuring out how to code more advanced actions has become a challenge for me.

My assignment is to compute the TF-IDF of a corpus of 10 documents. But I am stuck on how to tokenize the corpus and print out the number of tokens and number of unique tokens.

If anyone can help or even step step guide me in the right direction, it would be so greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hey! More context around the question might help give you a better answer but i've put together something quick which I think gives you a start. The bottom of the answer has two links which might help understand tfidf in context. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

This might help.

I have a collection of individual text file which I want to ingest and fit transform to the TfidfVectorizer. This will walk through the process of ingesting the files and using TfidfVectorizer.

I went to [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/nltkdata/movie-review/data) to get some example data about movie reviews

I used the negative (neg) reviews. For my purposes, it doesn't matter what the data is, I just need some textual data.

Import required packages

```
import pandas as pd 
import glob
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
```

How will these packages be used?

- we're going to use pandas to stage the data for TfidfVectorizer
- glob will be used to gather the file directory locations
- TfidfVectorizer is the star of the show

Gather the file locations using Glob

```
ls_documents = [] 
for name in glob.glob('/location/to/folder/with/document/files/*'):
    ls_documents.append(name)
```

This will produce a list of file locations.

Read the data from the first 10 files

```
ls_text = []
for document in ls_documents[:10]:
    f = open(document,"r")
    ls_text.append(f.read())
```

We now have a list of text.

Import into Pandas

```
df_text = pd.DataFrame(ls_text)
```

Rename the column to make it easier to work with

```
df_text.columns = ['raw_text']
```

Clean the data by removing any rows with nulls

```
df_text['clean_text'] = df_text['raw_text'].fillna('')
```

You might chose to do some other cleaning. It is useful to keep the raw data and create a separate 'clean' columns.

Create a tfidf object - I'm going to provide it with english stop words

```
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')
```

fit and transform the clean_text we created above by passing tfidf the clean_text series

```
tfidf_matrix = tfidf.fit_transform(df_text['clean_text'])
```

You can see the feature names from tfidf

```
tfidf.get_feature_names()
```

You'll see something which looks like this

```
['10',
 '13',
 '14',
 '175',
 '1960',
 '1990s',
 '1997',
 '20',
 '2001',
 '20th',
 '2176',
 '60',
 '80',
 '8mm',
 '90',
 '90s',
 '_huge_',
 'aberdeen',
 'able',
 'abo',
 'accent',
 'accentuate',
 'accident',
 'accidentally',
 'accompany',
 'accurate',
 'accused',
 'acting',
 'action',
 'actor',
....
]
```

You can look at the shape of the matrix

```
tfidf_matrix.shape
```

In my example, I get a shape of

```
(10, 1733)
```

Roughly this means 1733 words (i.e tokens) describe 10 documents

Not being sure what you're looking to do with this you might find the two articles useful.

- This [article](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/recommender-systems-python) from DataCamp uses tfidf in a recommendation system
- This [article](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/text-analytics-beginners-nltk) from DataCamp has some general NLP processes
  techniques

Answer (score 0):

I kind of took a fun approach to this. I'm using the same data as @the_good_pony provided, so I'll use the same path.

We'll use os and re modules, because regular expressions are fun and challenging!

```
import os
import re

# Path to where our data is located
base_Path = r'C:\location\to\folder\with\document\files


# Instantiate an empty dictonary
ddict = {}

# were going to walk our directory
for root, subdirs, filename in os.walk(base_path):
    # For each sub directory ('neg' and 'pos,' in this case)
    for d in subdirs:
        # Create a NEW dictionary with the subdirectory name as key
        ddict[d] = {}

        # Create a path to the subdirectory
        subroot = os.path.join(root, d)

        # Get a list of files for the directory
        # Save time by creating a new path for each file
        file_list = [os.path.join(subroot, i) for i in os.listdir(subroot) if i.endswith('txt')]

        # For each file in the filelist, open and read the file into the
        # subdictionary
        for f in file_list:
            # Basename = root name of path to file, or the filename
            fkey = os.path.basename(f)

            # Read file and set as subdictionary value
            with open(f, 'r') as f:
                ddict[d][fkey] = f.read()
            f.close()
```

Sample counts:

```
len(ddict.keys()) # 2 top-level subdirectories
len(ddict['neg'].keys()) # 1000 files in our 'neg' subdirectory
len(ddict['pos'].keys()) # 1000 files in our 'pos' subdirectory

# sample file content
# use two keys (subdirectory name and filename)

dirkey = 'pos'
filekey = 'cv000_29590.txt'
test1 = ddict[dirkey][filekey]
```

Output:

```
'films adapted from comic books have had plenty of success , whether they\'re about superheroes ( batman , superman , spawn ) , o [...]'


### Simple counter dictionary function
def val_counter(iterable, output_dict=None):
    # Instanciate a new dictionary
    if output_dict is None:
        output_dict = dict()

    # Check if element in dictionary
    # Add 1 if yes, or set to 1 if no
    for i in iterable:
        if i in output_dict.keys():
            output_dict[i] += 1
        else:
            output_dict[i] = 1
    return output_dict
```

Using regular expressions, which I've overkilled here, we can clean up our text from each corpus and capture alphanumeric items to a list. I've added an option to include small words (1 character in this case), but getting stopwords wouldn't be too tough.

```
def wordcounts(corpus, dirname='pos', keep_small_words=False, count_dict=None):
    if count_dict is None:
        count_dict = dict()

    get_words_pat = r'(?:\s*|\n*|\t*)?([\w]+)(?:\s*|\n*|\t*)?'
    p = re.compile(get_words_pat)

    def clean_corpus(x):
        # Replace all whitespace with single-space
        clear_ws_pat = r'\s+'
        # Find nonalphanumeric characters
        remove_punc_pat = r'[^\w+]'


        tmp1 = re.sub(remove_punc_pat, ' ', x)

        # Respace whitespace and return
        return re.sub(clear_ws_pat, ' ', tmp1)

    # List of our files from the subdirectory
    keylist = list(corpus[dirname])


    for k in keylist:
        cleand = clean_corpus(corpus[dirname][k])

        # Tokenize based on size
        if keep_small_words:
            tokens = p.findall(cleand)
        else:
            # limit to results > 1 char in length
            tokens = [i for i in p.findall(cleand) if len(i) > 1]


        for i in tokens:
            if i in count_dict.keys():
                count_dict[i] += 1
            else:
                count_dict[i] = 1

    # Return dictionary once complete
    return count_dict



### Dictionary sorted lambda function

dict_sort = lambda d, descending=True: dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=descending))

# Run our function for positive corpus values
pos_result_dict = wordcounts(ddict, 'pos')
pos_result_dict = dict_sort(pos_result_dict)
```

Final processing and printing:

```
# Create dictionary of how frequent each count value is
freq_dist = val_counter(pos_result_dict.values())
freq_dist = dict_sort(freq_dist)


# Stats functions
k_count = lambda x: len(x.keys())
sum_vals = lambda x: sum([v for k, v in x.items()])
calc_avg = lambda x: sum_vals(x) / k_count(x)

# Get mean (arithmetic average) of word counts
mean_dict = calc_avg(pos_result_dict)

# Top-half of results.  We count shrink this even further, if necessary
top_dict = {k:v for k, v in pos_result_dict.items() if v >= mean_dict}

# This is probably your TD-IDF part
tot_count= sum([v for v in top_dict.values()])
for k, v in top_dict.items():
    pct_ = round(v / tot_count, 4)
    print('Word: ', k, ', count: ', v, ', %-age: ', pct_)
```